# Vba runtime error 91 or 1004 every now and then when using Listobjects.Add

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Im trying to create a table from a range and sometimes works and other timers i get runtime error 91.

Im using the next excel code:

```
Sub TABLA()
    Dim app As Word.Application
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim openExcel, openExcel5 As Workbook
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
    Set openExcel2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("insert path here")

    excelApp.Visible = True
    openExcel2.Worksheets("FORM").Select
    openExcel2.Worksheets("FORM").Range("A1:D13").Select

    Set rango = openExcel2.Sheets("FORM").Range("$A$1:$D$17")

 
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$17"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"

   

End Sub
```

I have tried looking for other ways to make a table but havent found it, every place y search the code should be correct.

Comment: Start by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and declare all variables. Be aware that if you are declaring multiple variables on the same line, you must add the variable type to **each** variable and not just at the end, else the other variables will by of type variant. Do not use `ActiveSheet`.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: It is good practice to always declare your variables. In the VBA GUI, you can enforce this by `Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings` and selecting `Require Variable Declaration`. This will place `OPTION EXPLICIT` at the top of each inserted module (and you can also manually add this to modules created before you selected this option). This will be extremely useful in catching typos, variables of the incorrect type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the assignment of the name property.
Do something like this

```
set myObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$17"), , xlYes)
myObject.Name = "Table1"
```